# Temporal : Query on Promise with get() method call

Tags: java, temporal, temporal-workflow

SDK : Temporal Java SDK

In the workflow code, we're trying to resolve the promise with get() method call, since its blocking call, i've below queries team, can you please clarify on this -

whether the workflow worker's main thread will be blocked or will it initiate new thread and resolve that promise.
whether the workflow worker will get into sleep mode and it will get invoked when promise gets resolved.

In high level, we understand that get() method will block the main workflow thread.

Comment: I'm having a lot of difficulty understanding your question as it currently stand.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you mean the following: "I'm writing a Temporal Workflow using the Java SDK. In my Workflow code, I have some Promise object, on which I call `.get()` to await for that promise completion. Q1: Will this block the Worker's main thread until the promise resolves? Q2: Will this cause resource usage (for example: threads, memory or CPU) on the worker machine until that Promise resolves? Q3: Will the Worker be able to fall into some kind of sleep mode until the Promise resolves?"

Comment: If my understanding of your question is not correct, please reformulate your question by yourself. You may want to use some automated tool to translate your question from your own language to English.

Comment: Also, get a look at advices given on [this page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers). In particular, **avoid politeness constructs**. They are not required (this is a help site and people expect you to ask for help), and makes your question confusing. For example, you use the word "query" twice in your question... Is your question specifically about sending a query to a workflow?